# Why is this anon subroutine declaration parsed as an indirect object method in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, anonymous-function

In the following anonymous subroutine declaration, Perl seems to be parsing it as an indirect method call, rather than as a subroutine:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub proxy {
    my $new = shift;
    say "creating proxy: $new";
    sub :lvalue {
        say "running proxy: $new";
        tie my $ret, 'Some::Package', shift, $new;
        $ret
    }
}

say "before";
my $p1 = proxy '_value';
say "p1 declared: $p1";
my $p2 = proxy 'value';
say "p2 declared: $p2";
```

which prints:

```
before
creating proxy: _value
running proxy: _value
Can't locate object method "TIESCALAR" via package "Some::Package" ...
```

If a `return` or `my $sub =` is added right before `sub :lvalue {...`, then everything works properly, and it prints:

```
before
creating proxy: _value
p1 declared: CODE(0x4c7e6c)
creating proxy: value
p2 declared: CODE(0x1ea85e4)
```

It also works if the `:lvalue` attribute is removed from the subroutine (but of course that changes the functionality).

So my question is why is this happening?  Is this a bug in Perl related to attributes on anonymous subroutines?  Is it for some reason an expected behavior?  If it is a bug, is it registered?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the beginning of a statement is a valid place to find a `goto` label, and so the bareword `sub` followed by a colon token is parsed as the label `sub:`, which is followed by `lvalue BLOCK`, which is parsed as indirect object syntax.

If you force the parser to look for a term by doing `return sub : lvalue { ... }` or `my $foo = sub : lvalue { ... }` it parses as intended.